# undefined reference to Error when making c++ file including opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

I'm trying to make a cpp file that simply displays an image :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;
int main(){

    Mat img;
    img = imread("img.jpg",1);
    if (!img.data){
        std::cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("my window", 1);
    int key = 0;
    while (key != 27){
        imshow("my window", img);
        waitKey(10);
    }
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

and I am using this Makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-W -Wall -ansi -pedantic -I/usr/include/opencv2
LDFLAGS=-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_objdetect
EXEC=DetectRT
SRC= $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ= $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean mrproper

clean:
    rm -rf *.o

mrproper: clean
    rm -rf $(EXEC)
```

However, when I'm making I get errors like :

```
Test.o: In function `main':
Test.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
```

Comment: OpenCV version? If >= 3.0 you need to link also to `opencv_imgcodecs`. And for your convenience use `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`